# Losing one line of text file in For Loop

Tags: python

My For loop skips the first line each time I read one line at a time.
The problem doesn't occur when I just need to read in the entire file into memory, but mostly I need to read in one line a at a time.

Here's one example where the problem occurs.
This loop just reorders the elements in a list.
I've omitted the lines where I open and close read & write files (the clunky way I do it). Its all comma delimited text data.

```
lineString=fileItemR.readline()

for lineString in fileItemR:
    lineList = lineString.split(",")
    newList = (lineList[1],lineList[0],lineList[2:99])
    lineItem = str(newList)
    formatString = lineItem.replace("('","").replace("', '",",").replace("', ",",").replace("['","").replace("\\n","\n").replace("'])","")

    fileItemW.write(formatString)
```

Comment: Your for loop does no such thing. The line before the for loop explicitly reads the first line and then you do nothing with it.

Comment: downvoted because stackoverflow is not your debugging tool, pdb.set_trace() is.

Comment: how are you updating the lineString inside the for loop?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's the first `readline()` (the one you call before the loop) that eats your first line.

Comment: Thanks! I actually was wondering about this after I asked (after spending quite a while wondering before that). I guess the readline reads the first line, and then the For Loop follows on in sequence on the unread lines. I'll drop the first line outside the loop. This is basically a operation I repeat over and over in one program, so it solves a problem that I was having to devise a bodge for to solve. The 'solution' ran out of rope today though! ;-) Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Your problem is you read off the first line of the file and don't do anything with it

```
lineString=fileItemR.readline()
```

remove this and you should be ok

You can also achieve this a bit more simply:

```
for lineString in fileItemR:
    lineList = lineString.split(",")
    lineList[0], lineList[1] = lineList[1], lineList[0]
    fileItemW.write(",".join(lineList[:99]))  #Don't use [:99] if there's only 100 items in the line, and this could change in the future. If you're discarding items past the 100th then this is fine.
```

Comment: yep, that sorts it. Thanks!